# Does an index improve all kinds of queries?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, indexing

Assume I have a book table defined as follows:

```
table book(id varchar(50), title varchar(100),type varchar(20),publisher varchar(20), price float)
```

Suppose an index is defined on ID. Now queries which uses the ID will be improved, like:

```
select * from book where id='abcd123456'
```

But will queries that uses other fields be improved as well? For instance, these two queries:

```
select * from book where title = 'algorithms'
select * from book where price > 25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't. However, if there is an index on one column, and the query involves that column and others, it will work out to use the index, if it can.

Comment: Not really "if it can", more like "if it is beneficial".

Answer (score 2):

Everybody who's getting into sql performance tuning should read [Tuning by cardinality feedback by Wolfgang Breitlingi](http://www.centrexcc.com/Tuning%20by%20Cardinality%20Feedback.pdf)

As to your question - oracle will choose an index access path only if it's cheaper then accessing the entire table. it does that by estimating the cost for each execution plan.

In your example, if `id` is unique then oracle expects 1 row - the index cost is accessing the index head + reaching the leaf (usually 2 block reads) + table block access (usually 1 block) - total of ~ 4 CR.
Performing an FTS (Full Table Scan) will result in reading all the blocks in the table. The cost is the number of blocks in the table divided by `db_file_multiblock_read_count`.
If the FTS cost is more then 4 oracle will perform an index unique scan.

About the second questions with the non unique predicates - if oracle estimates that `price > 15` will result in less rows he will prefer the index access, otherwise he will prefer the FTS access.

The article explains all that beautifully.